# advantages of using play framework over scala alone?

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm new to Scala and **I'd like to learn it**, but I realize that exist a framework based on scala named play, which is totally new to me as well, from that point of view, I'd like to know what are the advantages of using play framework vs scala alone, what are the risks for someone that's is completely new to both technologies?

it could be the case to learn scala first and then move to play framework? it would be better to learn play framework since the very beginning.

for the big social networks so far it seems like:

- twitter is using scala
- linked in is using play

Comment: Scala (language) is knowledge about flour, sugar, salt. Play (framework) is recipe for a cake. You do not need to doctorate about plants and minerals, but still can be good baker. Depends on your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Play framework is a web MVC framework. Scala is a language. Play is written in scala, but they are totally different things.
Play can be used also from Java, you don't have to use scala with it (althought it's much nicer).
Learn scala if you want to learn a new and interesting JVM language.
Use Play if you need to build a web application and you want a modern JVM based web framework.

Comment: thanks makes sense, it could be the case to learn the framework and at the same time it's kind of mandatory to learn the programming language

Comment: Since scala and Java are interchangeable you don't really need scala to use play. You can use Play in Java as well.

Comment: @Pedro if you're totally new to Scala I would first learn the Scala language before learning Play. If you try to learn both at the same time you're probably making it hard for yourself.